# Google Calendar sync with JAVA - JdoCredentialStore

Tags: java, mysql, calendar, synchronization

I have JAVA WEB application written in Eclipse that uses examples from here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

Everything works fine. The user credentials are saved locally to a .store directory and I can create events.

```
// Directory to store user credentials
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/calendar-sync");
```

Now, instead of saving the credentials locally, I want to save each user's credential to my MySQL database. I saw few examples to use JdoCredentialStore, which doesn't exist in the latest release 1.2 anymore.

[Duplicate entry Exception using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow with JdoCredentialStore and DataNucleus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420727/duplicate-entry-exception-using-googleauthorizationcodeflow-with-jdocredentialst)

Is there a substitution for JdoCredentialStore and if yes where I can find examples or do I have to revert back to 1.16, in which JdoCredentialStore still exist? Google's documentation does my head in.

Thanks,
Tom